# Android Studio Java Bitmap Factory returns null

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to load .png file from resources, following code prints "img is null!" so BitmapFactory returns null, but Android Studio IDE doesn't show any errors.

API 16

```
img = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.triangle_435);
if(img == null) {
  System.out.println("img is null!");
}
```

[image: Res folder]

Comment: triangle in api 24 folder, are you running the app on API 24+?

Comment: I'm using API 16

Comment: Maybe you are importing the wrong R reference. check your import and make sure that you are importing your project R file and do not import android.R;

Comment: i'm using the right reference to R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is available for only API 24 and above(as indicated by v24).

Move your image to `drawable` folder to use the default `drawable` folder which provides the resources for all android versions and sizes.

To view the complete hierarchy, click on the project view instead of android

[image]

in the project navigation section(on left of code editor) and do the following. You can also use the `refactor` option on the image to move it to a different folder or try copy and paste, Android studio will provide you the options to paste in different `drawable` directories.

Read more about [Providing alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources) and read about `Platform Version (API level)` in the table.

Comment: There is only one drawable folder and my image is already in it as shown in the attached image, what other drawable folder are you talking about?

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel the current view of your project is android, change it to `project` to see all the files/folders. added an image in the updated answer.