# android studio png bitmapfactory.decoderesource returns null

Tags: android

on my M1 macbook air using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1, I have a bg.png file in my drawable folder of my app.  when I run this
background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.bg);
background is null and my app crashes.
image is 1024 x 512 dp @ mdpi
Why is it returning null?  I searched my title in stackoverflow and got no hits.

`
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

public class BitmapBank {

```
Bitmap background;


public BitmapBank(Resources res ) {
    background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res,R.drawable.bg);


}

// return background bitmap
public Bitmap getBackground(){
    return background;
}

//return background width
public int getBackgroundWidth() {
    return background.getWidth();
}

// return background height
public int getBackgroundHeight(){
    return background.getHeight();
}
```

}`

If I hover of the .bg in the background line above it brings up a picture of the background in the code window of android studio so I know it is referencing the correct image.

many google searches and nothing worked.

I also tried these

[Android: BitmapFactory.decodeResource returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501863/android-bitmapfactory-decoderesource-returning-null)
and

[Android Studio Java Bitmap Factory returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61643753/android-studio-java-bitmap-factory-returns-null)

and no luck

Comment: "image is 1024 x 512 dp @ mdpi" -- try moving the image from `res/drawable/` to `res/drawable-nodpi/`.

Comment: I did and no change. still null.